# Can Coded UI be able to assert the disoriented text?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Say we have a script written to assert "InnerText" property of a HTML control.
So we assert "Login Now"and it passes.

Now, say on the browser it is displayed as

> "Login
>                                                  Now"

Still CodedUI will pass it.

Is there any way this can be checked?

Comment: share some code please, that you have tried and that which is not working.

Comment: This is actually not about code. Its about if Coded UI has this feature or not. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking. The displayed text does not read clearly, the source of the question (see via the [edit]) link appears to put "Login" and "Now" on separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original assert checks that the string is `Login Now` but the web page has changed so that the browser shows the two lines:

```
Login
Now
```

then the assert will fail because the string is `Login\r\nNow`. (From the question it is possible that the string also has some spaces, so it could be `Login \r\n   Now`.)

There are at least two ways of handling this.

First you could do two asserts. One that the inner text **contains** `Login` and the other that it contains `Now`. But this would pass the strings `Now Login` also `You must Login Now` and that could be wrong.

Another approach is to read the inner text value, remove any leading and training spaces, convert any intervening white space to a single space, then finally do the assert. If the original assert is something like

```
Assert.Equals(innerText, "Login Now");
```

then you could replace it with something like:

```
Assert.Equals(Regex.Replace(innerText.Trim(), "\\s+", " "), "Login Now");
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @AdrianHHH